# How to wrap a command line tool into an app and properly quit it?

Tags: c++, macos, packaging, terminate

I have a multi-threaded command-line program in C++. When launched from the terminal, I can properly quit with `q <RET>`, which will call a series of clean_up routines which will eventually release all resources. Note that if `q <RET>` is never pressed the program just loops forever. Note also that the program launches some GUI Windows on its own.

I need to wrap this tool as an app - nothing really fancy, just a nice icon with all the necessary assets inside it so that simple users can launch it simply by double-clicking. I've used Platypus with success to make such an app in the past.

However I can't find a way to properly quit the program. There is no way to `std::cin` in my program from there and I reckon that on quit (from the menu or cmd-Q) platypus just sends a SIGTERM or something similar to my program (I can't really use this to properly clean my application - I need to end the infinite loop on main and have all destructors called implicitly when leaving main).

Isn't there any other easy way to wrap my program as an .app, but in a way that I can call a particular function on quit? I thought of creating a dummy app with Cocoa/Swift, make my program a static lib and call it from there, but there has to be a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd wrap it with an application that uses the [Qt Framework](http://www.qt.io/), which also uses C++.

Using [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) to launch the program, the documentation states: -

> The QProcess class is used to start external programs and to communicate with them

Here's a simple example of what you can do...

```
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Main application class
    // Use QCoreApplication instead, if this is not a GUI app
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // launch the process with the given arguments
    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
    myProcess->start(program, arguments);

    if (!myProcess.waitForStarted())
        return -1;

    // quit the app as soon as it has started, but 
    // just for demonstration purposes
    myProcess.write("q"); 

    return app.exec(); // starts the event loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a handler for SIGTERM in your app.

Here's a program I wrote that does this, but in C it's a common practice to bind signals to handlers with the "signal" function.  Given that you're using C++, you can use C with it directly, or find the equivalent thing in C++ (of which there surely is an identical construct).  The key thing is to use the signal function to bind signal with handler.

https://github.com/jpnorair/otter/blob/master/main/main.c